# Delegate using different methods of different classes

Tags: c#

```
using System;

 delegate int NumberChanger(int n);
 namespace DelegateAppl
 {
   class TestDelegate
   {
     static int num = 10;
    public static int AddNum(int p)
     {
      num += p;
      return num;
     }

     public static int MultNum(int q)
    {
      num *= q;
     return num;
    }
  public static int getNum()
  {
     return num;
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     //create delegate instances
     NumberChanger nc1 = new NumberChanger(AddNum);
     NumberChanger nc2 = new NumberChanger(MultNum);

     //calling the methods using the delegate objects
     nc1(25);
     Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", getNum());
     nc2(5);
     Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", getNum());
     Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

in the above code function called and calling function are in same class.... can we use like both in seperate classes?

if its possible please give an example ......

Comment: Do you have a very specific scenario in mind? If you do, just try it out or logically you'd know. Without specific scenario in mind.. It is unclear what you are asking..

Comment: For me its very clear what he is trying to achive. But nevertheless I aggree on @VikasGupta and you should just try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can.

Just put your methods in a separate class and create an instance of it to access them:

```
class Arithmetic
{
    int num = 10;
    public int AddNum(int p)
    {
        num += p;
        return num;
    }

    public int MultNum(int q)
    {
        num *= q;
        return num;
    }
}
```

Now call the methods:

```
class TestDelegate
{
    public delegate int NumberChanger(int n);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create instance of class
        Arithmetic art = new Arithmetic();

        //create delegate instances
        NumberChanger nc1 = new NumberChanger(art.AddNum);  //call with reference
        NumberChanger nc2 = new NumberChanger(art.MultNum); //call with reference

        //calling the methods using the delegate objects

        //add
        Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", nc1(25)); //use it directly because your delegate returns a value

        //product
        Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", nc2(5)); //use it directly because your delegate returns a value

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Note:** You don't need `getNum()` method as you are already returning value from every method and your delegate returns it as well. Also I have removed `static` from everywhere because it seems you need it.

Comment: no need to remove the static keyword i think...
it works with (classname.functionname) like arithematic.addnum

Comment: As you wish. But you won't be able to reuse the class with `static`.